# Replace characters in link in java

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a string that contains some text and a link that looks like this:

```
String str = "Some random text blabla. <a href=\"https:\/\/www.google.com\">Google<\/a> Some other text lalalalalla";
```

How can I remove all `\` in the string in Java?

Comment: There should not be any '\' characters in that String. You seem not to understand the concept of a string escape sequence.

Comment: @PatrickParker original sting contains additional double quotes and we need to escape them. `" ...<a href=\'"google.com\"> ..."`

Comment: @Anton you misunderstood. The literal representation of the string in the code file does have '\'. But the actual java.lang.String does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String originalString = "\\asda\\2ee43r3\\";
String newString = originalString.replace("\\", "");
```

Ps: the string you posted is not valid, you don't need to escape the / character.